# Java regex to find a sequence of a single char and a sequence of numbers

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex, that solves the follwing task:
   - input - a single char from a to j and a single number after the char from 1 to 10 (inclusive)

Correct: `a1`, `a2`, `f3`, `b7`, `c10`
Wrong: `a11`, `b0`, `abv`, `a34`, `h11`, `1c`

I've tried these: `^[a-j]{1}[0-9|10]{1,2}$` `^[a-j]{1}[0-9]{2}$`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've tried these: ^[a-j]{1}[0-9|10]{1,2}$; ^[a-j]{1}[0-9]{2}$

Comment: What is the problem with those? Also, use the 'edit' link to update your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it.

```
"^[a-j]([1-9]|10)$"
```

The first bracket matches the single letter, then there is an alternative which is either a single digit or the number 10.

```
^[a-j]{1}[0-9|10]{1,2}$
```

A `{1}` is redundant. `[0-9|10]` means: any of the characters 0, 1,... 9 or `|`, because `[]` acts like a set expression, with - for ranges. Also, you would permit this single character to be written once or twice, which would match a11, a12,...j99 etc.

```
^[a-j]{1}[0-9]{2}$
```

Better, but permitting any two digits after the letter.

Comment: Ahh. I knew that I am missing something! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

`[..]` is character class where you can specify single characters like `[abc]` will mean `a` or `b` or `c`. If you write it like `[10]` it will mean `1` or `0`, not `10`.

So instead of `[0-9|10]` which means `0` or `1` or .. or `9` or `|` or `1` or `0` you need to write something closer to `[0-9]|10` (notice position of `]`).
Also `{1}` is redundant.

Rest of your regex seems fine.